# What is the difference between Source IP address and IP address in header in WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

In Web Application Firewall,I set IP range group,I'd like to restrict access only from these Ip groups.
In following snapshot,I can select `Source IP address` and `IP address in header`,But what is the difference between them? I confused in which case should I select each.
If someone has opinion or materials, please let me know.

Thanks

[image: WAF]

Answer (score 4):

**Source IP Address:** is the IP address of the entity from where the request is coming from. This might be the client who initiated the request or might be intermediary such a load balancer, CDN etc.

**IP Address in header:** most of the time we care about the IP address of the client who initiated the request, not the address of a certain proxy (like a load balancer or CDN). Usually, if the request goes through a proxy, the IP address of the client is saved in a header (which typically is called `X-Forwarded-For`). More about this can be found in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-forwarded-ip-address.html).

Comment: So "Source IP Address" is coming from somewhere other than the header? Are there any docs on how this IP address is obtained?